# reflect lower.tri to upper.tri

Tags: r, matrix

if we have:

```
 mat <- matrix(c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,NA), nrow=,4)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    1   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    2    4   NA   NA
#[4,]    3    5    6   NA
```

and we want

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA   1   2   3
#[2,]    1   NA   4   5
#[3,]    2    4   NA   6
#[4,]    3    5    6   NA
```

What should we do?

I tried:

```
 v <- mat
 v[upper.tri(v)] <- t(v[lower.tri(v)])
# same as v[upper.tri(v)] <- (v[lower.tri(v)])
```

but this reveals

```
 v
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA    1    2    4
#[2,]    1   NA    3    5
#[3,]    2    4   NA    6
#[4,]    3    5    6   NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `as.dist` and wrap it in `as.matrix`:

```
as.matrix(as.dist(mat))
#   1 2 3 4
# 1 0 1 2 3
# 2 1 0 4 5
# 3 2 4 0 6
# 4 3 5 6 0
```

Or, more specifically (but somewhat cryptically)...

```
`diag<-`(`dimnames<-`(as.matrix(as.dist(mat)), list(NULL, NULL)), NA)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA    1    2    3
# [2,]    1   NA    4    5
# [3,]    2    4   NA    6
# [4,]    3    5    6   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

got it

```
v[upper.tri(v)] <- (t(v)[upper.tri(t(v))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Overkill, but you can also use `forceSymmetric`

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(forceSymmetric(mat, "L"))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA    1    2    3
# [2,]    1   NA    4    5
# [3,]    2    4   NA    6
# [4,]    3    5    6   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `byrow = TRUE` in `mat`

```
mat <- matrix(c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,NA), nrow=,4)
matrix(mat, 4)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]    2    4   NA   NA
# [4,]    3    5    6   NA

(mat1 <- matrix(mat, 4, byrow = TRUE))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA    1    2    3
# [2,]   NA   NA    4    5
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA    6
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA


mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat1[upper.tri(mat1)]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA    1    2    3
# [2,]    1   NA    4    5
# [3,]    2    4   NA    6
# [4,]    3    5    6   NA
```